# Load data from CSV file to AWS Aurora Serverless (PostgreSQL) db

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-aurora-serverless

**Scenario**:
We have a source SQL database table which gets updated every 24 hours. I am designing an automated process which would export that table to `CSV` file to an EC2 instance after the update of the source DB happens.

**Problem**:
I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to load a CSV file containing DB records from a table exported with **[bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)** command-line utility to Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL database.

My current plan is to generate a bunch of `insert` statements from that `CSV` file using a [script](https://github.com/pavanchhatpar/csv-to-sql-converter)

Then use the AWS CLI on the EC2 Linux instance to talk to the Aurora DB and execute the following:

```
// empty the table 
AWS rds-data execute-statement --transaction-id $ID --database users --sql "delete from mytable"
```

Use the **Data API** feature of Aurora Serverless to run a transaction such as:

```
$ $ID=`aws rds-data begin-transaction --database users --output json | jq .transactionId`
// populate the table with latest data
$ aws rds-data execute-statement --transaction-id $ID --database users --sql "insert into mytable values (value1,value2)"
$ aws rds-data execute-statement --transaction-id $ID --database users --sql "insert into mytable values (value1,value2)"
$ ...
$ aws rds-data commit-transaction $ID
```

Is there a better way to load that CSV file to the Aurora DB? Or I should stick with the above solution.

**Note**:
I found that article on AWS docs - "*[Loading data into an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster from text files in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)*" but it explicitly states that `This feature currently isn't available for Aurora Serverless clusters.`